# How to include a base class without any ROS2 functionality in 2 different ROS2 packages

Tags: ros, ros2, cmake, roscpp

I have a base class which contains some generic functions and they're not ROS related.

An example of this class would be:

```cpp
class Engine
{
public:
  explicit Engine(const NetworkOptions & options);
  ~Engine();
  // Build the network
  bool build(
    std::string & onnxModelPath);
  // Load and prepare the network for inference
  bool load_network();
  // Run inference.
  bool run_inference();
};
```

2 of my ROS2 packages need to inherit from that base class and add some ROS2 functionality like subscribing to a topic and publishing.

An example of one of the ros nodes that need to inherit from it can look like this:

```cpp
class Yolo : public Engine, rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  bool run_inference() override;
};
```

so it needs to inherit from both the Engine class to be able to use the build, load functions etc., but will override the run_inference function because it is network specific and it will subscribe to a particular ros topic.

What i have been doing so far is including the header file of the base class in each of my neural network projects, but i know that this is not the best practice because i will be copying the same files in each ROS2 package. will it be better to make the base class a static library or make it as an ament package while exporting its targets, dependencies etc., what is the best practice here?

Help is much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to robotics, Mostafa. Have you already tried something to do that?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mostafa_Hegazy, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: It's not clear if your issue is putting a base class in one CMake project and subclassing in another (in which case [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10487256/5171120) may be helpful) or if it's about how to create a ROS publisher or subscriber (in which case [this tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) may be helpful). Please try to get something implemented ask questions after if you're still having trouble. I'd recommend returning here for ROS-specific questions, and [SO] for CMake questions.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I edited my question with what i have and what i tried, please take a look at the updated version. My issue is with the best practice too, i don't know what is the best practice in my particular case.

Comment: Only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/280335) please - so you might want to trim the last paragraph from your last edit (in order to get the question re-opened). Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, you will (obviously) need to include the header file (`.h`) corresponding to your "`base file.cpp`" in any `.cpp` file that calls functions/members of your base class, just so that the contents of the `.cpp` file knows that the base class member exists somewhere.  However, you really seem to be asking about how to organise your classes in a ROS project. While I don't pretend to know the answer, I would look at the advanced examples/projects online and survey how they are organised and (if there are multiple ways) then chose the most popular or prevalent.

Comment: `i know that this is not the best practice` - Could you qualify that statement a little? Why and how do you know that? Could you link to any references..? It could be useful for others with the same belief. Please [edit] and update your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i updated the question again. I need to include the header files indeed. but i only should do it once and not have to copy the file contents to every package that i make, "don't repeat yourself" behavior. I know how to organise my classes if they were all using the ROS meta system, but my problem here is that the base class doesn't use ROS at all, so that's why i am kinda lost.